# Identify an missed call/incoming call number and service provider / location / geography in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, location

Can any one know how to identify a missed call/incoming call number and service provider / location / geography in iPhone sdk.

Comment: Even if I could tell what you were asking, you're asking questions worth about five separate questions, each of which has been asked a LOT here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the Missed Call or the Incoming Call Data using the iPhone SDK in the first place.

Even if you could, the location or geography of the third party where the call is made is not transmitted to your device so you can't trace the location or the service provider. You could link the Cell Phone Number to a Service Provider if you had data on the prefixes of all the operators.